# Cisco 2911 - display location using the show line command

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

On a Cisco 2911 terminal server, if I run the command `show line`, it will present info about the console ports like this:

```
0/0/0    3 TTY   9600/9600  -    -      3    -    -   116    162  671/0       -
0/0/1    4 TTY   9600/9600  -    -      4    -    -    84    128    0/0       -     
0/0/2    5 TTY 115200/115200-    -      5    -    -    90 332670 28661/0      -
0/0/3    6 TTY 115200/115200-    -      6    -    -    76 332664 28180/0      -
```

What I would like is to see the "Location" parameter displayed alongside all the lines. Right now, I can view it by looking at the details of an individual line like `show line 0/0/1`, but I'd like to be able to pull the parameter for all the lines at once. Is there a way to do this in IOS?

Comment: I accepted @user208145's answer since it's correct, there isn't a way without using some other tool. However, his suggestion of using telnetlib, shogo2022's suggestion of using tcl are good approaches. I ended up using a Python script with netmiko and textfsm, then found the [ntc-ansible](https://github.com/networktocode/ntc-ansible) Ansible modules that use the same textfsm modules, but handle all the connection logic and concurrency for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on a 3560 switch.

```
Cisco IOS Software, C3560 Software (C3560-IPBASE-M), Version
12.2(25)SEE2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

Switch   Ports  Model              SW Version              SW Image
------   -----  -----              ----------              ----------
*    1   28     WS-C3560G-24PS     12.2(25)SEE2            C3560-IPBASE-M
```

If I use `show line` I get the output you described, as well as the verbose info when I use `show line X`. The `show line ?` help indicates a first and last int number can be used to get a range, but again it only displays that summary table.

```
#sh line ?
  <0-16>   First Line range
  console  Primary terminal line
  summary  Quick line status summary
  vty      Virtual terminal
  |        Output modifiers
  <cr>
```

If I were a magic 8 ball, I'd say all signs point to no, it's not possible.

Is this something you would be comfortable scripting? I've used Python's telnetlib library to automate getting switch health stats. I read that Expect can do this too, but I haven't used that.

Comment: I could script it out using netmiko, but since it's going to issue 64 commands on one terminal server (it has 64 console ports defined), and I have 20+ terminal servers to hit, it's going to take a while to gather all the data

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is the tcl. I don't have the cisco unit at hand and cannot try, but the code should be something like this.

```
    tclsh

    set lines [ exec "show line" ]
    foreach intf [ regexp -all -line -inline {[0-9]\/[0-9]\/[0-9]+.} $lines ] { 
    set detail [ exec "show line $intf" ]
    regexp {.*Location: (.*)\,} $detail location
    puts "$intf : $location"
    }

    tclquit
```

If you have full control on the router, you can save this script and you can simply run it.

Comment: I'll check this out on Monday. Didn't know TCL was available on these devices